# Connection Error for Heroku Redis Addon (error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, heroku-redis, heroku-addon

I am using Heroku for hosting my Express.js app.
Recently I have upgrade the redis addon of my app that deployed on Heroku from 5.X to 7.0.
And I have upgraded the redis module version to latest (4.6.7) in my codebase.
But I am getting following error after deploying to Heroku.
And it is not working on my local env as well, but can't see any redis connection error log in my local env.

```
Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

I have just followed the guide from Heroku for the connection.
Following code snippet is my redis config:

```
import * as Redis from 'redis'
import { REDIS_CONNECTION } from './../../constants';

const url = REDIS_CONNECTION;

export const createRedisClient = () => {
  return Redis.createClient({
    url,
    socket: {
      tls: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  })
};
```